# Determine the value of $a$ so that $f$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 2t^2 + at + 1 & t < 1 \\ 2t - a/\sqrt{t} & t \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

This is a really confusing question for me I'm not sure how to do the bottom part any help?

Comment: What exactly is confusing?

Comment: And what does it mean in your language to "do" the "bottom part"???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $f$ is continuous for all $t \neq 1$ independent of $a$. For $t =1$, one has $f(1) = 2 - a$ and

$$\lim_{t \uparrow 1} f(t) = 2 + a + 1, \qquad \lim_{t \downarrow 1} f(t) = 2 - a.$$

Now it must be

$$2 + a + 1 = 2 - a, $$

hence

$$a = - 1/2.$$